# Enumerate all installed system fonts

Tags: html

I was creating a html editor and needed to offer a drop with a list of all fonts. Is it possible to enumerate all fonts on the system with html5?

Comment: Certainly it is, why not? A list is nothing but a set of strings. Font names are strings. Wether you place them in html later does not change that. So if you have a way to ask the set of available fonts from your system, then you certainly can place them in a html list. _However:_ keep in mind that you can only access the fonts installed or available _on the server_ which are pretty useless in html programming. You _can not_ somehow access the fonts on the client side (so where the browser is used).

Comment: Oh shoot, so its not possible to get the installed fonts like on Windows, Mac, Linux?

Comment: I would consider that as a pretty huge privacy issue.

Comment: Not those installed on the client, no. Like with all other things: the browsers won't grant you to interact with local things for a _very_ good reason. That would be a _huge_ security and privacy issue.

Comment: Question is: _why_ do you want to have a list of the client side available fonts? What for?

Comment: @arkascha I want to put it in a drop down like this - http://i.imgur.com/UW9WgcG.png

Comment: That was an explanation of _what_ you want to you. It did not answer my question _why_ you want to do that.

Comment: I'm creating an editor, and i want to show the user the fonts and what they look like so they can pick.